# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==8.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gis

When i run the following command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade --no-cache --no-cache-dir
```

I am getting the following error message. How to solve the problem?

```
Collecting Pillow==8.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==8.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0rc1, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.2.0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2)
No matching distribution found for Pillow==8.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Comment: What python and pip version are you using?

Comment: python 3.8 version i am using

Comment: how to know pip version?

Comment: it must be pip then, `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: it is giving some other error. error .

Comment: You could make a backup of your `requirements.txt` and then just delete `==8.1.2` and see if you can *"get away with"* a slightly older version.